# Adding a number in sequence to a .txt file name

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I need help with adding numbers to text files. The txt files in the folder should look something like this:

```
Ref1.txt
Ref2.txt
Ref3.txt
...
```

And here's my code:

```
var
  RefNumber : Integer;
  newFile : TextFile;
  RefA, RefB, RefC : String;
begin
  RefA := edtRefA.text;
  RefB := edtRefB.text;
  RefC := edtRefC.Text;
  RefNumber := 1;
  inc(RefNumber);
  System.AssignFile(newFile + RefNumber, 'C:\Users\Files\newFile.txt');
  System.Rewrite(newFile + refNumber);
  WriteLn(newFile, RefA + RefB + RefC);
  System.CloseFile(newFile + RefNumber);
end;
```

I know `System.AssignFile(NewFile + Refnumber, '');` is incorrect.

How would I achieve this if it is possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change a text file name string not the file variable:

```
  System.AssignFile(newFile, 'C:\Users\Files\Ref'+IntToStr(refNumber)+'.txt');
  System.Rewrite(newFile);
  WriteLn(newFile, RefA + RefB + RefC);
  System.CloseFile(newFile);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing the file handle and the filename it's associated with.

```
    Var
  lFilename : String;
  lRefNumber : Integer;
  lTextFile : TextFile;
Begin
  lRefNumber := 1;
  lFileName := Format('Ref%d.Txt',[lRefNumber]);
  System.AssignFile(lTextFile, lFileName);
  System.Rewrite(lTextFile);
  WriteLn(NewFile, RefA + RefB + RefC);
  System.CloseFile(lTextFile);
End;
```

Note that using the old Textfile way of file handling has been superceded by TFileStream and it's descendants.